# Anyone know how to use Regex in notepad++ to find Arabic characters?

Tags: regex, unicode, notepad++, arabic

I am trying to detect Arabic characters in a webpage's HTML using Notepad++ CTRL+F with regular expressions. I am entering the following as my search terms and it is returning all characters.

```
[\u0600-\u06FF]
```

Sample block of random text I'm working with -

```
awr4tgagas
بqa4tq4twْq4tw4twtfwd
awfasfrw34جَ4tw4tg
دِيَّة عَرqaw4trawfَبِيَّ
```

Any ideas why this Regular Expression won't detect the Arabic characters properly and how I should go about this? I have the document encoded as UTF-8.

Thanks!

Comment: @Oxhughes, I'm curious why you preferred the answer you accepted as I answered your question and provided background links two minutes before the answer you chose. Can I ask why you preferred the other answer to mine? Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is happening because Notepadd++ regex engine is PCRE which doesn't support the syntax you have provided.

To match a unicode codepoint you have to use `\x{NNNN}` so your regular expression becomes:

```
[\x{0600}-\x{06FF}]
```

Answer (score 11):

Because Notepad++'s implementation of Regular Expressions requires that you use the

```
\x{NNNN}
```

notation to match Unicode characters.

In your example,

```
\x{0628}
```

can be used to match the `ب` (bāʾ,bet,beth,vet) character.

The `\u` symbol is used to match uppercase letters.

See http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Regular_Expressions#Ranges_or_kinds_of_characters

for an explanation of Notepad++'s regex syntax.