# Regular Expression match special symbol like "®"

Tags: regex, symbols

seems ".*" cannot match "®" I'm not sure why this special symbol is in the URL. It shows like "xAE" in Notepad++.

Does someone can help me? Thanks!

Comment: the URL is like "www.example.com:443/dvtp_src.js?ctx=10309481&cmp=11225034&sid=2555202&plc=149478553&num=&adid=&advid=2116933&adsrv=1ϩon=30&btreg=&btadsrv=&crt=&crtname=&chnl=&unit=&pid=&uid=&tagtype=&app=&sup=&DVP_EXID=&DVP_CDID=&DVP_DMGRV=&DVP_LAT=&DVP_LONG=&dvtagver=6.1.src 192.168.1.1" -------------  I tried to use "  sed 's/:.* / /'  " to have the "  www.example.com  192.168.1.1 "

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Anyone know how to use Regex in notepad++ to find Arabic characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18411903/anyone-know-how-to-use-regex-in-notepad-to-find-arabic-characters)

Comment: Try `[.\x{00AE}]*`.

Comment: I'm using notepad++ with utf8, and I am finding that '.' matches to the '®' character. I can't reproduce your error.